# Black Screen on Laptop

Tags: boot

I had a working Lenovo G580 laptop I wanted to change to Linux.  I chose Replace Current OS.  Now I have a Laptop that is not working.

The screen stays black with nothing happening.  No startup logo, no light, just dark black all the time.

I tried to make a DVD-R ISO by downloading Ubuntu and burning it to a DVD-R disc and a USB device.  You can hear the DVD-Drive trying to read the DVD, but nothing shows on the screen and the USB also does not work.

Also connected a monitor to the VGA port, but that monitor just says: No Connection.

The Ubuntu website does not help, because the screen stays totally black.  I cannot fix software problem if I cannot browse the screen.

Comment: Please try bootoption nomodeset https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Comment: I tried connecting the HDMI slot to my TV and toggle Fn + F3 as per a windows site that say that toggles the output.  Nothing.  Screen totally black.  I did not check the BIOS boot sequence before I tried to install Ubuntu.  I tried the Novo Button with the Ubuntu ISO in the DVD and without.  You can hear the DVD drive start up, then a small fan for about a minute and a little white LED above the screen lights up, but after a minute or so, the fan stops and the white LED goes dark.